# Alzheimer's disease - Hyperexcitability

Tags: brain, medicine, cell-signaling

I am trying to read literature on Alzheimer's disease.
A very important phenomenon that occurs in AD patients, is hyperexcitability in neurons close to A-beta concentrations.
Some authors only describe the phenomenon of hyperexcitability in excitatory cells as an indirect phenomenon, which results due to the suppressed function of inhibitory cells.
Some other authors only describe it as the direct result of excessive concentration of Glutamate in a synaptic cleft which, due to the dysfunction of Astroglia, remains there and causes hyperexcitability and excitotoxicity.

I haven't found yet a paper where both are mentioned as distinct ones. At least I haven't found any that I could comprehend, given that my background is not biomedical.

I would like to know if these two cases I mentioned before, are indeed distinct ones, or if they are the same, and I cannot see it due to lack of knowledge.

Comment: The answer would require expertise in that specific field. I would suggest you to get in touch with some of the authors whose papers you mentioned, you read.

Comment: We can help, do you have the refs handy? otherwise i will look it from scratch.

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler thanks a lot! The references are the following:

as an indirect phenomenon: [link](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-18729-5)

as a direct phenomenon: [link](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31395777/)

Comment: I  might be a week, is this still useful?

Comment: of course! many thanks for the willingness to help